# How to add javascript code between Body tags using an extension?

Tags: joomla-3.x, extensions

I need to add javascript (this is for Google phone call conversation) and it must go between the `<body>` and `</body>` tags. It's going to be the same code for all the web pages on the site. Is there a Joomla extension to do this? I often use Flexi Code, but I don't see a way to place this between the body tags only. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need an extension for that. Just open the `index.php` of your website template (`templates/your_template/index.php`) and add it there.

Please note that some templates providers change the structure and the main file is not `index.php` file.

You can do it over FTP or from the control panel of your website: Extensions -> Template Manager -> Choose Template on the left -> Select your template.